# react-router-dom NavLink isActive does not work well

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are working on a project using React.js. I am configuring multiple pages utilizing react-router-dom, and I want to change the currently active icon using NavLink.

icon+sel is for active page.

```
render() {

  const oddEvent = (match, location) => {
    if (!match) {
      console.log(!match)
      return false

    }
    else{
      console.log(!match)
    }
    const eventID = parseInt(match.params.eventID)
    return !isNaN(eventID) && eventID % 2 === 1
    console.log(eventID)
  }

  return (
      <fragment>
        <div className="bottom noright">
          <div className="bottomcontents">
            <div className="bottomicon">
                <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" src={home} exact to="/" isActive={oddEvent}>
                <img className="iconcenter" src={!NavLink.match ? homesel : home}/>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/about" isActive={oddEvent}>
                <img className="iconcenter" src={!NavLink.match ? searchsel : search}/>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/about/foo" isActive={oddEvent} >
                <img className="iconcenter" src={!NavLink.match ? addsel : add}/>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/posts" isActive={oddEvent}>
                <img className="iconcenter" src={!NavLink.match ? accountsel : account}/>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/" isActive={oddEvent}>
                <img className="iconcenter" src={!NavLink.match ? settingsel : setting}/>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            {/* <div className="search"></div>
            <div className="plus"></div>
            <div className="mypage"></div>
            <div className="setting"></div> */}
          </div>
        </div>
          </fragment>
    );
}

}

export default Bottom;
```

Comment: You say that it doesn't work well, but what's the behaviour you are getting?

Comment: I want the icons to change according to the page, but it does not work well.

Comment: I think that it's not working because your component is not refreshing, you should consider using setState and set your icon depending on the state of your navlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `isActive` prop of `Navlink` and also you are using it incorrectly.
Instead, you could declare a variable `isActive` and change its value based on the route and then change icon src or class based on `isActive` flag.

Basic Code below:-

Clicking on `I am inactive` link will change the color to green and change the text to `I am active`. Similarly you could change src of image. Also you can find [codesandbox working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zr8xm0910p) for reference.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/topics">Topics</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

class Topics extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location } = this.props;
    let isActive = false;
    if (location.pathname === `${match.url}/props-v-state`) {
      isActive = true;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}
              activeStyle={{ color: "green" }}
            >
              <div>
                {isActive ? (
                  <span>I am active</span>
                ) : (
                  <span>I am inactive</span>
                )}
              </div>
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
        <Route
          exact
          path={match.path}
          render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Topic({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

Actually with react-router-dom v6 you don't need to declare that isActive variable; it's there by default in NavLink component. The code below sets a border-bottom and some opacity on the link text when the link is active.

```
<NavLink style={({isActive})=>({
                    borderBottom: isActive ? "#15b0ab solid 2px": '',
                    opacity: isActive ? 1 : ""
                })} to='/project>Projects'</NavLink>
```

Note: this only works with NavLink and not Link component and it should be import from react-router-dom@v6

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink to="/react-project" className='text-decoration-none' style={{ color: "white" }}>
    {({ isActive }) => (
        <h3>
            {isActive ? (
                <span>React Projects</span>
            ) : (
                <span><FaChevronLeft /> React Projects</span>
            )}
        </h3>
    )}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those whose isActive prop not working on NavLink and want the manual way.

First get the current url:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

Then using condition to apply class "active" which is default serve by react-router-dom

```
 <NavLink to={"/normal/create/text"} 
  className={ ['/normal/create/text','/normal/create/file'].includes(pathname) ? 'active': ''}>
                  <span>Click here</span>
  </NavLink>
```

The NavLink above will work for both ***/normal/create/text*** and ***/normal/create/file***

Answer (score -1):

I realize this question was answered a long time ago but there is a simpler solution in 2023 with React Router 6+. By default, an *active* class is added to a  component when it is active so you can use CSS to style it.

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <NavLink to="/messages" />
</nav>
```

```
#sidebar a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Source: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#default-active-class

Comment: but this answer is not wrong, why down vote it?